# Disable a Wordpress site

Tags: plugins

Hello I plan to disable my wordpress website. I don't plan to permanently delete it from the web. What are the steps I must follow to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to create a file called 'maintenance' and place it in your sites root folder. When WP sees that file, it puts up a 'down for maintenance' type file. You can still get into the admin area, but the 'public' can't see the file.

Another way is to rename the '.htaccess' file (which helps redirect access to the site into WP pages) and create a new index.php/html file (renaming any existing one). That index file would contain an 'under construction' message or something similar. Disadvantage of that would be no access to the admin area.

Which technique you use depends on the length of the downtime. Temporary downtime: I'd use the 'maintenance' file technique. Longer-term: I'd build an 'under construction' page as index.html or index.php (renaming any existing files of that name) and rename the '.htaccess' file.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer. I was actually able to set my website to offline for maintenance by going into admin>settings>site offline mode. It was an easy fix.

Comment: Well, that's another way. Glad it worked out for you. If my answer was helpful, please click the checkmark icon. Perhaps all this will be helpful for others getting here via the googles. Note that creating a 'under construction' page might be useful to your visitors (or customers), so they will know to return later, rather than abandoning your site.